# Objective-C: How to declare/define method used on tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My initial problem of multiple line selection in a `UITableView` has been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057819/didselectrowatindexpath-selecting-more-than-one-row-at-a-time) question. But the answer left me at a point where I can't go on on my own, as I am very new to Objective C and iOS development.

Following [daxnitro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760958/daxnitro)s answer, I want to implement the code he/she suggested:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView indexPathIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        [tableView removeIndexPathFromSelection:indexPath];
    } else {
        [tableView addIndexPathToSelection:indexPath];
    }
    // Update the cell's appearance somewhere here
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

I still need the methods and I thought I can do it for `indexPathIsSelected` (for example) like this:

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()
- (BOOL)indexPathIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

// ...

- (BOOL)indexPathIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL bIsSelected = NO;
    // ...
    return bIsSelected;
}
@end
```

But that doesn't work. The error message is: *No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'indexPathIsSelected:'* Note: The same happens, if I declare the method in the .h file's interface instead.

Now, what baffles me, is this: `[tableView indexPathIsSelected:indexPath]` is somehow called on the `tableView` object and I don't even know why. Is that something I have to take into account in my method declaration/definition? I feel really stupid right now, that I can't even write a method by seeing its invocation.

How do I define and declare the method `indexPathIsSelected` correctly, so I can use it properly?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375122/how-to-select-multiple-rows-in-uitableview

Comment: @mrunal The poster has a specific problem with his current approach, totally re-doing it with another approach is overkill.  I think this is a one-line fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, the variable `tableView` is a `UITableView`.

Your implementation for `indexPathIsSelected` is in class `MyTableViewController`, which is *probably* a `UITableViewController`.

`UITableViewController` and `UITableView` are different classes.

So you can't find the method `indexPathIsSelected` on `UITableView` because it's not implemented there, it's implemented on `MyTableViewController` which is a different class.

SO... I'm going to take an educated guess and assume that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is part of class `MyTableViewController`.  If this is the case, then

```
[self indexPathIsSelected:indexPath]
```

may be the answer (i.e. call `indexPathIsSelected` in `self` rather than the table view).

Comment: That removed the error message, thank you! I allready thought I had to change something in the framework of `UITableView.h` And thank you for the explanation. If that doesn't lead to far and just for my understanding: With `self` I reference to the `MyTableViewController` and with `tableView` I reference to the superclass `UITableView`, right?

Comment: You are correct:  `self` is an instance of `MyTableViewController`, which is a subclass of  `UITableViewController`.  `tableView` is an instance of `UITableView`.  (Actually I *guessed* that your `indexPathIsSelected ` method was implemented on `MyTableViewController` but it looks like a correct guess; that's the natural place to implement that.)

Comment: In the mean time I ran my code and it worked finally. Not only it works but I also understand my mistake thanks to your explanation.  So thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is the key to the problem. The method `indexPathIsSelected` is implemented in your custom class `MyTableViewController`. However, the UITableView you have is apparently still a basic `UITableView`. At the very least you'll need to go into the storyboard and set the custom class of the table view controller object to `MyTableViewController`.

To do this, open the storyboard (or nib) and select the table view controller. Then in the identity inspector (on the right hand side, typically), under custom class, select `MyTableViewController` from the drop down.

Comment: Just double checked it and the custom class is correctly set to `MyTableViewController`. It worked before, I just had the problem mentioned in the linked question. But thank you for your quick and friendly answer!